# Smooth Scroll the Header Navigation Links using Jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have made a bootstrap based single page template and added navigation.
I want to add smooth scroll and tried a few tuts and plugins but none were helpful.
I have added sections for respective links
Help is appreciated.
My URL : http://hrcvizag.com
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
$('#menu-main li a').click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

This assumes that the HREF of each list item will consist of "#" and then the ID of the section. So, for example, the HREF value for Services is #services and so on.